# Android 5.0 getExternalMediaDirs() undefined

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

in my app (currently working fine in KITKAT) i want to add and use the getExternalMediaDirs() but i get "The method getExternalMediaDirs() is undefined" error.

My SDK Manager screenshot: [sdk manager](http://postimg.org/image/w919erwtd/)

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
     try{
         File[] directories = getExternalMediaDirs();
     }catch (Exception e) { Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
 }
```

My manifest contains

```
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

Is it too early to use this function or is it something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 21 or higher on Android Studio. In Eclipse, in Project > Properties > Android, choose a build target of 21 or higher.

Comment: Weird, i don't remember setting this property for older APIs. But anyway, it worked, Thanks!

Comment: @LazarosPapadopoulos: `getExternalMediaDirs()` is new to API Level 21, so you need to compile against API Level 21.